# Norm of orthogonal projection matrix - vectror product

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have an orthogonal projection matrix $\mathbf{P}$ with dimensions $n \times n$ and $\mathbf{P}^T=\mathbf{P}$.
Then by properties of projection matrices, we know that for any vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$\|\mathbf{Px}\|_2\leq \|\mathbf{x}\|_2.$$
Under what conditions the equality holds in the above inequality?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\|x\|^2 = \|Px\|^2 + \| (I-P)x \|^2.$

Comment: Well, I understand that necessary condition is that $\mathbf{Px=x}$, that is when $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{span}(V)$ where V is the space in which matrix $\mathbf{P}$ projects to.. Correct?

Comment: Yes it is necessary and sufficient.